# Configure DB to respond only from a specific IP address

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a server with multiple IP addresses (say ... 10.1.1.10 & 10.1.1.11) with several databases.
And I want to say DBx is only responding if the client uses the IP 10.1.1.10 and DBy is only reachable with the IP 10.1.1.11

I have found lots of example when you restrict the allowed client ip address but nothing so far for sticking DBs on dedicated IP address

any idea ?

Comment: Look into `listen_addresses`.

Comment: Are these different databases on the same PostgreSQL instance (aka "cluster"), or different instances?

Comment: @dezso thanks I will look at it.
@  jjanes at current time all in one cluster.